# Adding direct dial shortcuts to my app

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

I'm making an app that can launch other apps.  I've got it launching apps fine using Spinners, however, I would also like to give the user the ability to launch direct dials from it.

As it is right now I've got "hot key" buttons that the user can configure.  Currently, when the user wants to configure one of these "hot keys" I use a spinner to let them choose from all the installed applications on their phone.  For starters, I would like it if they are able to view both installed applications and shortcuts in the spinner so that they can map a direct dial to one of these "hot keys."

So my main questions are, how can I go about looking up all the defined shortcuts available and execute them and how could I create my own direct dials in my app?

Answer (score 0):

To dial a number directly

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + NUMBER)));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple function for this

```
public static void go2Call(Context context, String phoneNo) {

    Intent intent = null;
    Uri destUri = null;
    /*
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html
        <uses-permission id="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        tel: phone_number
     */

    if(DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "go2Call ->" + "phoneNo:"+phoneNo);
    phoneNo = PhoneNumberUtils.convertKeypadLettersToDigits(phoneNo);
    if(DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "go2Call ->" + "phoneNo(normalized):"+phoneNo);


    if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo) ) {

        destUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo);
    }

    if (destUri!=null) {
        intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, destUri );
    }

        if ( intent!=null && isIntentAvailable(context, intent) ) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            // TODO: display error msg
            Log.w(TAG, "error pr intent not available! ->" + "phoneNo:"+phoneNo);
        }
    }
```